# The Database Server on EasyPHP won't start

Tags: java, mysql, database, service, easyphp

i have some issues to work on a local database. I tried Wamp, but the services doesn't work, so I try EasyPHP and they doesnt work either.
In other words, when i try to start the service (http server and/or databaseserver) on the EasyPHP dashboard, nothing happen !

But when i click on start, the page is loading then refreshing but nothing actually happend.

However, in my services window, the two services are running, so i don't understand what happend.

The issue is that i can't go to my phpmyadmin interface on the EasyPHP dashboard, because there is no "Open" button.

In images : https://i.stack.imgur.com/6j5D7.jpg

I am pretty sure it's because of a proxy i have to used in my company. But i can't figured out what to do now. I also try to connect to the database using JDBC on Java, and the connection is running until a timeout says "No Internet connection" while i actually have one, but i use it through a Proxy...

Thanks for anyhelp, i'm on this for 8 hours x(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind !

It was just needed to start easyPHP as an Administrator.

I'm feeling stupid x)

Answer (score 0):

On my pc I had 2 instances of MySQL running.
I went to the Services and turned off MySQL57.
Then the EZphp server database could connect.
I think that they both were using the same port 3306, so one of them could't use the port.

Comment: What are you asking? 2 services (of any type) can't use the same port indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried everything listed above and sadly nothing has worked.

My Solution was moving the EasyPHP-Devserver-17 folder from "Program files x86" to "Program files" folder. re-run and just worked!

Good Luck! it's not a straight forward error.